# Is there the creator overseeing us all. How does He do that?

Tags: metaphysics, death, life, universe, self

Is there the creator overseeing us all. How does He do that?

Is that possible due to His omnipresence and being independent of 3+1D (x, y, z, ct) limitations?

---

My previous question and related to this:

[I always feel as if someone is watching me, but only at night. What does this mean?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/i-always-feel-as-if-someone-is-watching-me-but-only-at-night-what-does-this-me)

Comment: "Is there the creator overseeing us all" ? Maybe... according to most religions, the answer is : YES.

Comment: "How does [the creator] oversee us all ?" Because the creator (i.e. God) is [Omniscient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omniscience).

Comment: We came from our parents, and on up the line to the source or origin. So it stands to reason that we are somehow related to the source or origin, which obviously is much bigger and more universal than (yet includes as a subset) the human species. Being somehow physiologically related (DNA, organic matter, energy, etc.) suggests some level of communication and interest, or we wouldn't be here in the first place. In my experience God is personally interested in me, and so presumably in every other individual as well.

Comment: From my reading of Plotinus the "How does he do that?" is a critical question. If you shift the mental image of this creator from being a God to being something like a field (space-time, gravitational, electromagnetic)  but also super-personal and alive, the *how* may not be as difficult to conceive, or no more difficult than the influence of gravity. Welcome. I see you have a new user account as well.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I thought it is the case only for abrahamic religions. Buddhism, Hinduism, Zoroastrianism, most folk religions, etc. do not have such an omniscient creator.

Comment: @Bread, this looks like non sequitur. What is source of origin? Big Bang?

Comment: @rus9384 The source / origin is the universe / all that exists.

Comment: @Bread, then since you are a part of the universe and you are overseeing yourself, it's true that you've been being overseen by the universe too. But I am not sure this makes sense. And what does it have to do with God?

Comment: @rus9384 "*...it's true that you've been being overseen by the universe...but I am not sure...and what does it have to do with God?"* You may have a problem with equating either your own or what you perceive as the standard accepted definitions of "God" and "universe", semantically. And it's reasonable to state that for many people both words share the quality of being indefinable, yet of course that doesn't prevent any of us from trying anyway.

Comment: @Bread, I do not accept standarts. Just it is a trend to call anything God nowadays.

Comment: @rus9384 *"it is a trend to call anything God nowadays"* :) The universe is everything, not "*any*thing". *"I do not accept standarts."* You might want to consider accepting at least some standards (the logical ones).

Answer (score 0):

Once again, nearly all of life's questions, and most of their suggested answers, can be found in science fiction.

Thinking you're being watched? Douglas Adams had something interesting to say.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM735uHc7o0

He also has something to say about trying to figure out if there is some grand plan to reality.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKUgqq-xOxw

Which is pretty ironic considering that the guy speaking here actually created the Earth.

When you can't get any evidence or convincing argument that something is or is not true, then hang the sense of it. Go on with your life as best you can, keep your eyes and ears open, and put such questions aside until new information becomes available.